How to handle an EPOLLHUP event?
Here's a demonstration code:
# server.py

import socket
import select

import time


event_name_map = {
    select.EPOLLIN: 'select.EPOLLIN',
    select.EPOLLOUT: 'select.EPOLLOUT',
    select.EPOLLPRI: 'select.EPOLLPRI',
    select.EPOLLERR: 'select.EPOLLERR',
    select.EPOLLHUP: 'select.EPOLLHUP',
    select.EPOLLET: 'select.EPOLLET',
    select.EPOLLONESHOT: 'select.EPOLLONESHOT',
    select.EPOLLEXCLUSIVE: 'select.EPOLLEXCLUSIVE',
    select.EPOLLRDHUP: 'select.EPOLLRDHUP',
    select.EPOLLRDNORM: 'select.EPOLLRDNORM',
    select.EPOLLRDBAND: 'select.EPOLLRDBAND',
    select.EPOLLWRNORM: 'select.EPOLLWRNORM',
    select.EPOLLWRBAND: 'select.EPOLLWRBAND',
    select.EPOLLMSG: 'select.EPOLLMSG',
}


def main():

    print(event_name_map)

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0) as server_socket:
        print(f'server_socket.fileno: {server_socket.fileno()}')
        server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 12345))
        server_socket.listen(10)

        with select.epoll() as epoll:
            SELECT_EVENT_TYPES = (
                select.EPOLLIN |
                select.EPOLLOUT |
                select.EPOLLPRI |
                select.EPOLLERR |
                select.EPOLLHUP |
                select.EPOLLET |
                select.EPOLLONESHOT |
                #select.EPOLLEXCLUSIVE |
                select.EPOLLRDHUP |
                select.EPOLLRDNORM |
                select.EPOLLRDBAND |
                select.EPOLLWRNORM |
                select.EPOLLWRBAND |
                select.EPOLLMSG
            )
            epoll.register(server_socket.fileno(), SELECT_EVENT_TYPES)

            socket_fileno_map:dict[int, ssl.SSLSocket] = {}

            while True:
                events = epoll.poll(0.1)

                for fileno, event in events:
                    print(f'event={event}: {fileno}')

                    if event & select.EPOLLIN:
                        print(f'EPOLLIN: {fileno}')

                        if fileno == server_socket.fileno():
                            connection, address = server_socket.accept()
                            print(f'connection from {address}')

                            connection_fileno = connection.fileno()
                            if connection_fileno in socket_fileno_map:
                                raise RuntimeError(f'fileno {connection_fileno} is already in the socket_fileno_map')
                            socket_fileno_map[connection_fileno] = connection
                            epoll.register(connection_fileno, select.EPOLLIN)

                        else:
                            for key, value in event_name_map.items():
                                if event & key:
                                    print(f'pending event {value} from file handle {fileno}')

                                    tmp_socket = socket_fileno_map[fileno]
                                    if event & select.EPOLLIN:
                                        data = tmp_socket.read(10000)
                                        print(data)
                                        print(len(data))
                                    elif event & select.EPOLLHUP:
                                        print('EPOLLHUP event')

                            time.sleep(1.0)

                    if event & select.EPOLLOUT:
                        print(f'EPOLLOUT: {fileno}')
                        
                    if event & select.EPOLLHUP:
                        print(f'EPOLLHUP: {fileno}')

            epoll.unregister(server_socket.fileno())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# client.py

import socket
import ssl


import time


def main():

    hostname = 'localhost'

    with socket.create_connection((hostname, 12345)) as client_socket:
        print(f'closing')
        client_socket.close()
        time.sleep(5.0)
        print(f'closed')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

It's relatively simple in what it does. The idea being to write a code which watches for any event types, and then learn how to handle each of them.
In this case, running the server, followed by the client, produces the following output by the server:
$ python3 server.py 
{1: 'select.EPOLLIN', 4: 'select.EPOLLOUT', 2: 'select.EPOLLPRI', 8: 'select.EPOLLERR', 16: 'select.EPOLLHUP', 2147483648: 'select.EPOLLET', 1073741824: 'select.EPOLLONESHOT', 268435456: 'select.EPOLLEXCLUSIVE', 8192: 'select.EPOLLRDHUP', 64: 'select.EPOLLRDNORM', 128: 'select.EPOLLRDBAND', 256: 'select.EPOLLWRNORM', 512: 'select.EPOLLWRBAND', 1024: 'select.EPOLLMSG'}
server_socket.fileno: 3
server_socket.fileno: -1
ssl_socket.fileno: 3
event=65: 3
EPOLLIN: 3
connection from ('127.0.0.1', 50624)
event=17: 5
EPOLLIN: 5
pending event select.EPOLLIN from file handle 5
b''
0
pending event select.EPOLLHUP from file handle 5
b''
0
EPOLLHUP: 5
event=17: 5
EPOLLIN: 5
pending event select.EPOLLIN from file handle 5
b''
0
pending event select.EPOLLHUP from file handle 5
b''
0
EPOLLHUP: 5
event=17: 5
EPOLLIN: 5

... and so it goes on forever.
So summarize my findings from this:

The client closing causes a pair of events EPOLLIN and EPOLLHUP
There are no bytes of data to read from the socket
Not sure what other operations I can try? (I tried read as it was the only sensible thing I could think to try. I'm not surprised there is nothing to read, however.)
These events persist, in other words, the loop continues forever telling me that there are pending events for EPOLLIN and EPOLLHUP, for the fd associated with the client socket.

So what should I do here? Why is the EPOLLIN event generated as well as the EPOLLHUP event?
How do I handle each of them? Each event type is a signal. Usually if something is being signalled, then something should be done to handle that signal. In this case, the infinite loop keeps signalling there are pending signals. What do we do with them?

If you read 0 bytes (w/o error) it means that the connection was closed by the other end. In this case you need to unregister any event listeners for the client socket and close it.

@SteffenUllrich That makes sense. Is unregistering the event listener the only way to stop it signaling? It seems trivially obvious that this will stop it, because there is no longer a mechanism for epoll to signal for an event for this fd. No other way to handle it? I guess I'm just a bit surprised by the behavior.

I'm not sure what other way you expect - the other side has closed so once you've realized this (i.e. read returned 0) there should be no need to check for EPOLLIN/EPOLLUP anymore - there cannot be any more data and there cannot be any other events after close. You thus basically ask if there is another way to disable a useless event listener except for unregister.

@SteffenUllrich I could be wrong but it feels as if the behavior is different for other functions. For example, if there is data to read, the event will be active until there is no more data to read. (Due to successive calls to read.) When the data has run out, the event stops firing. When you read 0 however, the event does not stop firing in this case. It seems - different?

"if there is data to read, the event will be active until there is no more data to read." - right, it does not get triggered on incoming data but will happen as long there are data in the socket buffer.  Same with EOF: it will not be triggered once on close from the peer but will  happen as long as the peer has the socket closed.

@SteffenUllrich fair enough, I guess it's sensible
